# How do I enable the password/pattern lock on HTC 2.3.5 (Sense) mobile?

Tags: lock-screens, htc-sense

I have an HTC (Sense UI) mobile running Android 2.3.5 and I am trying to enable the password/pattern lock but it is not working. I tried enabling the lock in my settings but when I turn on the screen it is not asking for the password, it is directly launching the home screen.

How do I enable the password lock?

Comment: Are you rooted and running a custom rom? Some roms have an option to disable lock screens. Other possibilities may be lock screen replacement apps

Comment: Please try to provide a screen shot of the settings or some details about the setting menu?

Comment: clarris, I don't have any other apps to lock the screen. Any way native locking feature is that one. It has to work. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Avirk, I tried to keep password like this: Settings -> Security -> options are here to keep the screen lock, If i kept the lock here but it is not applying the phone. Thanks

Comment: yes, Drake Clarris you are correct it has some custom rom. i successfully over come this issue. Thank you so much.